# iOS 14 SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable updateUIView doesn't detect ObservedObject changing?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

I have UITextView implemented by UIViewRepresentable.

```
struct CustomTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var tmpTextVM: TmpTextViewModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextView>) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.textColor = tmpTextVM.color
        
    }}
```

I want to use it like this.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var tmpTextVM: TmpTextViewModel
   
        var body: some View {

            VStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    tmpTextVM.changeColor(UIColor.red)
                }){
                    Image(systemName:"eyedropper.full")
                }
                
                CustomTextView(tmpTextVM: tmpTextVM)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(tmpTextVM.color))
                    .frame(width:300, height: 300, alignment: .topLeading)
                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                    
            }
    }
}
```

On iOS 13 if I tap the button, updateUIView is called and change that text color but on iOS 14 updateUIView isn't called. Are there any way to call view update by changing ObservedObject on iOS 14?

And here codes of TmpTextViewModel and its model.

```swift
    class TmpTextViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private var tmpTextModel: TmpTextModel = TmpTextModel()
    
    var color: UIColor {tmpTextModel.color}
    
    func changeColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        tmpTextModel.color = color
    }
    
}
```

```swift
struct TmpTextModel {
    
   var color:UIColor = UIColor.purple
    
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make ˋCustomTextViewˋ to listen to changes of ˋTmpTextViewModelˋ.

Just declare ˋtmpTextVMˋ in ˋCustomTextViewˋ as ˋ@ObservedOjectˋ.

```
struct CustomTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
   @ObservedObject var tmpTextVM: TmpTextViewModel
   //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This works fine! I don't understand why it was working on iOS13 tho...

Comment: I guess this is due to optimizations of the SwiftUI engine.

Comment: Ok, I see! Thanks for your help!!